# Webkit CSS rendering issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, webkit, rendering

I am currently having an issue in chrome with a webpage I am working on.  When the page loads, there is an odd space after an inline element.

Usually this would be caused by a margin, or some padding.  What is peculiar about this issue though is that it isn't.  If I disable a CSS rule then re-enable it, it fixes the issue.

The issue doesn't happen in Firefox, so as far as I know it is chrome specific.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Screenshot of said issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDLJG.png

Comment: The site itself can be found here: http://www.meivending.com.php53-8.dfw1-2.websitetestlink.com/j3/

Comment: @Mad-Chemist Try setting a width for `.ezb-mod .mod-post-title`, maybe 284px.

Comment: @imtheman The width needs to remain dynamic because the title length can change drastically.

Comment: @Mad-Chemist Ok, but if it gets too long you just want it to wrap around, right?

Comment: @imtheman Correct.  In theory, the title should stretch to the end of the element, pushing the date also, before wrapping.

Comment: @Mad-Chemist Ok, but you also want all of them to have constant space from the title to the date?

Comment: @Mad-Chemist Ok, have you considered putting them in a table. I think that will be the only way to do what you want. Well, the easiest way at least.

Comment: @imtheman The code is being outputted via a Joomla component.  I was hoping there was an explanation as to why it may be happening, recreating the output is always a possibility though.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by having javascript change the css after a short delay and change it back.  This emulates the solution that I mentioned viewing through using the inspector.

Since this is more of a work around than a solution, if anyone has any more information about the issue, feel free to comment.

Thanks.